# Screen brightness control (F1, F2) not working on a WASD mechanical keyboard with mac mode keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac, display

I got a WASD mechanical keyboard with mac mode keys which has the all the media shortcuts such as play, pause, volume up/down etc except for screen brightness control. Even though in System Preferences F1 and F2 are set up to control the screen brightness for my iMac, they don't work when I press them on their own or in combination with Fn/ Command/control/etc.

Is there a way that I can have keyboard shortcuts to screen brightness control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use software like Karabiner (free) to remap your keyboard keys. According to their documentation, mapping function keys to brightness settings is one of the settings it comes with.

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/